# Would like to add a line across the header with Logo on Left and Name on Right

Tags: header-footer, align

I'm trying to write a cover letter that has a logo on the left header and my name on the right header, with a line that runs across the top of the page. At the moment I have something like this:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,article, garamond addrfromright]{newlfm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\unprbottom{1cm}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\ps@ltrhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\g@addto@macro{\ps@othhead}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lastpage,calc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\newsavebox{\Ltlfoot}
\sbox{\Ltlfoot}{\scalebox{.65}{Tax Administration Research Centre, 
        University of Exeter Business School,
        Streatham Court,
        Rennes Drive,
        Exeter EX4 4PU}}
\newlength{\myfootheight}
\settoheight{\myfootheight}{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}


\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{2.7in}{\vspace{.5in}
    {\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image}}}}



\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{%
  \Lfooter{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}%
  \Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}\vspace{-50pt}}}
\Rfooter{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfooter{\usebox{\Ltlfoot}}
\rfooter{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=2pt, minfoot=\myfootheight}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}

\lthUiuc
\namefrom{xxx \\
xxx \\
xxx \\
University of Exeter Business School}
\addrfrom{
    xxx\\
    xxx \\
    xxx
}
\phonefrom{xxx}
\emailfrom{xxx}


\addrto{%
xxx\\
xxx \\
xxx \\
xxx
}

\greetto{Dear Members of the Search Committee:}
\closeline{Best Regards,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}


Sample Text 


\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

I like the footer a lot. But I can't figure out how to insert a name on the left side of the header and a line across the top header.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I can't compile your MWE. You should exchange the `taex` with `example-image` in the MWE. Also I get the error: `Undefined control sequence: \fancy@reset`

Comment: See the `fancyhdr` manual for `\headrulewidth`. For example `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}` in page 6

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to delete the fancyhdr. I included the example-image and should now compile.

Comment: I still get the very same error concerning `\fancy@reset`.